# Mailer::send() should not be called statically

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a site in laravel and after attempting to send mail. I get a error message:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

My code:

```
Mail::send('emails.kontakt', array('name' => 'Elvis'), function($message)
{
$message->to('edautovic99@gmail.com', 'Elvis')->subject('edautovic99@gmail.com');
});
```

Comment: Do you have the statement `use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer as Mail;` at the top of your file?

Comment: I think you just need to add use Mail; at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `\Mail::send()`, then you must have an alias in your `app/config/app.php` configuration file. Check out that file and look for an array of aliases which looks something like:

```
'aliases' => array(
    'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    // ...
)
```

Make sure that the alias `Mail` is in that array. It should point to the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail` facade.

So your aliasias array should look like that:

```
'aliases' => array(
    'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    // ...
    'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend a backslash to make sure you are using the Facade:

```php
\Mail::send('emails.kontakt', array('name' => 'Elvis'), function($message) {
    $message->to('edautovic99@gmail.com', 'Elvis')
            ->subject('edautovic99@gmail.com');
});
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the facade, it's better to inject the mailer in the constructor

```php
<?php namespace App\Some\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

class MyClass
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function doMyMailThing()
    {
        $this->mailer->send('emails.kontakt', array('name' => 'Elvis'), function($message) {
            $message->to('edautovic99@gmail.com', 'Elvis')
                    ->subject('edautovic99@gmail.com');
        });
    }
}
```